# Extrema of implicit functions - one point - two values?!

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am given this expression:
$$x^2+y^2+z^2-2x-2y-2z+2 = 0$$
And I need to find the extrema of the function 
$$z = z(x,y)$$
I did it in the following way:

1. Differentiate the expression with respect to $x$ and solve for $\frac{dz}{dx}$
2. Differentiate with respect to $y$ and solve for $\frac{dz}{dy}$
3. Find all tuples $(x, y ,z)$ such that $\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{dz}{dy} = 0$ given that both partial derivatives are continuous and exist.
4. Now, I got two points: $(1, 1, 0) $ and $(1, 1, 2)$ both of them turn out to be an extremum, but - to be honest - I do not know what is happening - why does this function have two outputs for one input?

Could you explain this to me in as simple terms as possible?

Answer (score 3):

If solved for $(z-1)^2$ it is one function $f(x,y)$ of $x,y$ but to get just $z-1$ (and then just $z$) one has to use $\pm \sqrt{f(x,y)}.$ So really *two* functions.

Comment: So this should be interpreted as follows: There are two curves satisfying this equation, one extremum either?

Comment: Yes, technically two *surfaces* satisfy it. (upper and lower hemispheres, as noted by Andrei.)

Comment: Note that in this case it is $(z-1)^2=f(x,y)$, so $z-1=\pm\sqrt{f(x,y)}$

Comment: @Andrei Thanks, will adjust.

Answer (score 2):

You have the equation of a sphere. When you calculate the extremum, you get the highest $z$ and the lowest one. You can rewrite the original equations as:
$$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2=1$$
You can write the equation for the upper hemisphere or the equation of the lower hemisphere

Comment: The problem states that $z = z(x,y)$. Does it not read as follows:
"$z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$."?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your equation for $z$
$$z_1=1-\sqrt{-x^2+2 x-y^2+2 y-1}$$
and
$$z_2=1+\sqrt{-x^2+2 x-y^2+2 y-1}$$
and differentiate this with respaect to $x,y$

Comment: I don' think this is the easier way to do this - I think this is way harder than implicit differentiation.

Comment: Ok, if you think so!